# Office365 Sharepoint Web Service Failing

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, office365

These two links:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/05/14/part-2-headless-authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model.aspx
- http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Post.aspx?id=601

Explain the same (but slightly varying methods) of connecting to Sharepoint online (office365 styles).

The sharepoint site I am trying to connect to is at http://thickshake.sharepoint.com/

I connect to https://thickshake.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0 and the response is MovedPermanently, and gives me the new url http://th... (same as before minus the http(s)). So I attempt to connect to that site and get `Object moved to <a href="%2f">here</a>.`

I feel like this is going in a never ending loop. I think I'm authenticating on https, it redirects me to http, and then won't accept the connection.

Does anyone have any experience with connecting to Office365's sharepoint that can shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is no https on sharepoint, only for the log in.

If anyone comes across this and needs help, you use Wictor's code (the second link in the post), but modify it so once you've called Https and been directed to http to get the FedAuth and rtFa keys, use those keys in calls to http pages :)

Comment: I am using the Wictor's code but where i am going to call Office365 Custom Domain link it get failed. Do you have any workaround to tackle Custom Domain links?Thanks